# regex not matching for multiple part of string

Tags: regex

I want to write regex something like

> /scheduling/groups/members/[list*|get*|search*].json

which should match with string

`/scheduling/groups/list.json` or

`/scheduling/groups/getGroup.json` or

`/scheduling/groups/searchMember.json`

and should not match with

> /scheduling/groups/save.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
\/scheduling\/groups\/(?:list|get|search).*\.json
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lA2gD7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Even could use something like

```
 # (?i)/scheduling/groups/(?:list|get|search)[^/]*\.json

 (?i)                          # Case insensitive modifier
 /scheduling/groups/           # Literal '/scheduling/groups/'
 (?:                           # Cluster group, one of either 
      list                          # 'list'
   |                              # or,
      get                           # 'get'
   |                              # or,
      search                        # 'search'
 )                             # End cluster group
 [^/]*                         # 0 - many characters that are non filename separators
 \. json                       # to get to '.jason'
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice even if there's many place to look at. Kudos for promoting non-capturing groups if no capturing is needed!

Comment: @fejese - Ok, added some explanation.